# It is possible to determine a text orientation by locale with intl extension?

Tags: php, intl

Can't find in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). 
May be exists undocumented method or some hacks.
Something like this:

```
Locale::getTextOrientation('en'); //returns Left-to-right
```

Or someone knows another extension/library to do this.